# correct refer to folder

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new to coding and I have some problem with referring to the right folder.

Here is my folder structure:

[image: folder structure]

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>AGONEX GmbH</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/fixed.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top">
      <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto" href="#"
        ><img src="/images/agonex.png" alt=""
      /></a>
    </nav>

    <div class="video-background">
      <div class="video-wrap">
        <div id="video">
          <video id="bgvid" autoplay loop muted playsinline>
            <source src="/images/agonex.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          </video>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caption text-center">
      <h1>Lorem</h1>
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" href="course">Lorem</a>
    </div>

    <!--- Start Course Section -->
    <div id="course" class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
        <h1>Lorem</h1>
        <p class="lead">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus,
          rem ut quos ex quibusdam nisi!
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--- End Course Section -->

    <!--- Script Source Files -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!--- End of Script Source Files -->
  </body>
</html>
```

And now my page looks like this:

[image: now]

Can someone please help me referring to the correct folder.

Sry for the "easy" question but I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to move any files you need to reference in your HTML into your `public` directory. So, for instance, `jquery-3.3.1.min.js` should be moved to your `public/js` directory, instead of your top-level `js` directory (which may be invisible to the browser... though I can't say for sure without seeing the contents of your `app.js` file). The same goes for your `bootstrap-4.3.1-dist` directory-- you can move the entire directory into your `public` directory.

Then in your HTML code, you can reference your jQuery and Bootstrap source files like this:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap-4.1.3-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for such a clear answer! It helped.

Comment: I'm glad to help. If you found my answer useful, I'd be very grateful if you could upvote it, too. Thanks!